# Implementing seq2seq with sampled decoder outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement seq2seq with a feature to generate sampled outputs from the decoder i.e. at every step, rather than taking the argmax of the output logits from previous state,  it should sample from them according to the logit distribution and use that as input for the next step.

After poking around I found the loop_function in seq2seq.py as a promising place to start.  It looks like I have to write a loop function that looks like this (modified from the one in the file that extracts argmax+embedding):

```
def _extract_sample_and_embed(embedding, output_projection=None,
                          update_embedding=True):
    def loop_function(prev, _):
        if output_projection is not None:
            prev = nn_ops.xw_plus_b(prev, output_projection[0], output_projection[1])
        prev_symbol = math_ops.sample(prev)  #<------- Need this op but it does not exist ?
        emb_prev = embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(embedding, prev_symbol)
        if not update_embedding:
           emb_prev = array_ops.stop_gradient(emb_prev)
        return emb_prev
    return loop_function
```

Then i use this loop function generator in the seq2seq_embedding_with_attention model. However, the op I need that samples from a tensor of floats does not exist in tensorflow, so do I need to write my own? How do I do that?

2. In searching for guidance, I found that in tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/candidate_sampling_ops there is a reference to :

   ```
           from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_candidate_sampling_ops
   ```

   but I can't find this file. I'm guessing it's auto-generated from somewhere. where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you can also do it as follows, with [the gumbel max trick for directe distributions](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/blog/2013/04/06/the-gumbel-max-trick-for-discrete-distributions/):

```
def batch_gumbel_max_sample(a, max_gumbel_noise = 1.0):
    matrix_U = -1.0*tf.log(-1.0*tf.log(tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(a),
                            minval = 0.0, maxval = max_gumbel_noise)))
    return tf.argmax(tf.sub(a, matrix_U), dimension = 1)
```

There is also a [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/456) on Tensorflows issue tracker about this at the moment. I guess sooner or later a multinomial sample function will be added to Tensorflow. LeavesBreathe also posted a work around on that Github page, which isn't entirely correct in my opinion:

```
def batch_sample_with_temperature(a, temperature=1.0):
'''this function is like sample_with_temperature except it can handle batch input a of [batch_size x logits] 
    this function takes logits input, and produces a specific number from the array. This is all done on the gpu
    because this function uses tensorflow
    As you increase the temperature, you will get more diversified output but with more errors (usually gramatical if you're 
        doing text)
args: 
    Logits -- this must be a 2d array [batch_size x logits]
    Temperature -- how much variance you want in output
returns:
    Selected number from distribution
'''

'''
Equation can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function (under reinforcement learning)
    Karpathy did it here as well: https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/blob/4297a9bf69726823d944ad971555e91204f12ca8/sample.lua'''
'''a is [batch_size x logits]'''
with tf.op_scope([a,temperature], "batch_sample_with_temperature"):

    exponent_raised = tf.exp(tf.div(a, temperature)) #start by reduction of temperature, and get rid of negative numbers with exponent
    matrix_X = tf.div(exponent_raised, tf.reduce_sum(exponent_raised, reduction_indices = 1)) #this will yield probabilities!
    matrix_U = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(a), minval = 0, maxval = 1)
    final_number = tf.argmax(tf.sub(matrix_X, matrix_U), dimension = 1) #you want dimension = 1 because you are argmaxing across rows.

return final_number
```

Comment: Yes, I also got it to work in seq2seq, forgot that you also need to propagate the tokens that you've chosen back to the output_feed. The function introduces randomness in the choices - but I'm still not convinced that it implements the Gumbel trick correctly. Shouldn't the Gumbel noise be directly applied to 'a'? And shouldn't it be −log(−log(Uniform(0,1)) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code I've ended up using. This is the correct Gumbel max trick in my opinion. It also produces better results. You can use the max_gumbel_noise parameter to control the amount of randomness that is introduced (similarly to temperature).

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem today, and my solution is:
Replace line

`prev_symbol = math_ops.sample(prev)`

with 

`prev_symbol = squeeze(multinomial(prev, 1), axis=1)`

The function tf.multinomial() draws samples from a multinomial distribution. It took a 2-D Tensor "logits" with shape [batch_size, num_classes], and a 0-D scalar "num_samples" as input. And output a drawn samples of shape [batch_size, num_samples].

Meanwhile, math_ops.sample() outputs samples of shape [batch_size], therefore we need tf.squeeze() to reduce dimension.

This implementation is simpler.